# Vuejs changing the selected target index to data from an array that pertains to the selection

Tags: vue.js

I am trying something different using vuejs, but i want to instead replace it with the nested array data instead of the selected text. As you can see, the selectedChar is displaying the name. Displaying the name there is fine, but in reality i would like to get the value of **subjects** there if that name is selected in the dropdown

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { Name: 'DonaldDuck',dept:'Disney',subjects: ["DA_", "AS_1E1", "VV_123", "AP_DS1"] },
      { Name: "Sonic", dept:'Marvel',subjects: ["SA_", "KSL_111", "DD_123", "GP_1SA1"]},

    ],
    selectedChar:'null'
  },
  methods: {
        changeZ (event) {
 
 
       this.selectedChar = event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text
       
       
      
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
<select id="dept"class="form-control" @change="changeZ($event)" style="width: 210px;">
  <option value="Select a Department" selected disabled>select a character:</option>
    <option v-for="t in todos" :value="todos.id" :key="todos.id">{{ t.Name }}</option>

</select>

 <p><span>You Selected: {{ selectedChar  }}</span></p>
```

instead. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really be utilizing `v-model` to bind the value of the `<select>` to a data property.  The Vue [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#select) specifically have a subsection on binding objects to `<select>` inputs. When you bind the whole object value you can then display any property of that object.

```html
<select
      id="dept"
      class="form-control"
      v-model="selection"
      style="width: 210px"
    >
      <option v-for="t in todos" :value="t" :key="t.id">
        {{ t.Name }}
      </option>
</select>

<p>
    <span>You Selected: {{ selection.subjects }}</span>
</p>
```

```js
data: {
    todos: [
      { Name: 'DonaldDuck',dept:'Disney',subjects: ["DA_", "AS_1E1", "VV_123", "AP_DS1"] },
      { Name: "Sonic", dept:'Marvel',subjects: ["SA_", "KSL_111", "DD_123", "GP_1SA1"]},

    ],
    selection: {}
  }
```

Comment: i dont think this is correct? do you have it working with the subject displaying in the javascript?  i mainly wanted to know how to change this line  this.selectedChar = event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text

Comment: Yes, this code is correct, it will display the entire subjects array.  This is the power of Vue.  Are you familiar with how v-model works?  It's what you want to use instead of messy event.target stuff.